# How to use a nested serializer dynamically for two serializers?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am working on an API, with Django, Django Rest Framework, and trying to achieve these(ad described)

#### First Serializer

```
class DeviceConfigSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    config = serializers.JSONField(initial={})
    context = serializers.JSONField(initial={})
    templates = FilterTemplatesByOrganization(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Config
        fields = ['backend', 'status', 'templates', 'context', 'config']
        extra_kwargs = {'status': {'read_only': True}}
```

Now I have two nested serializer containing the above serializer for the `LIST` and `DETAIL` endpoints:-

#### Second Serializer

```
class DeviceListSerializer(FilterSerializerByOrgManaged, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    config = DeviceConfigSerializer(write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta(BaseMeta):
        model = Device
        fields = ['id','name','organization','mac_address','key','last_ip','management_ip', 
                  'model', 'os', 'system', 'notes', 'config', 'created', 'modified',]
```

#### Third Serializer

```
class DeviceDetailSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    config = DeviceConfigSerializer(allow_null=True)

    class Meta(BaseMeta):
        model = Device
        fields = ['id','name','organization','mac_address','key','last_ip','management_ip',
                  'model','os','system','notes','config','created','modified',]
```

Now, I am using the same `DeviceConfigSerializer` serializer for `List`, and `Detail` endpoint, but for the list endpoint I have set the nested serializer as `write_only=True`, But What I am trying to do with the list endpoint that is `DeviceListSerializer` serilaizer is that out of all the fields from the `DeviceConfigSerializer`, I want the `status`, and `backend` fields to be both `read` & `write` and others fields as write_only.

Presently with this configuration I am getting the response from the `DeviceListSerializer` as this:-

```
{
            "id": "12",
            "name": "tests",
            "organization": "-------",
            "mac_address": "-------",
            "key": "------",
            "last_ip": null,
            "management_ip": null,
            "model": "",
            "os": "",
            "system": "",
            "notes": "",
            "created": "2021-04-26T10:41:25.399160+02:00",
            "modified": "2021-04-26T10:41:25.399160+02:00"
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is:-

```
{
            "id": "12",
            "name": "tests",
            "organization": "----",
            "mac_address": "-----",
            "key": "----",
            "last_ip": null,
            "management_ip": null,
            "model": "",
            "os": "",
            "system": "",
            "notes": "",
            "config": {
                 "status": "...",
                 "backend": "...",
            ,}
            "created": "2021-04-26T10:41:25.399160+02:00",
            "modified": "2021-04-26T10:41:25.399160+02:00"
}
```

PS: I tried by introducing an extra serializer for this two fields and nest it to the `DeviceListSerializer`, but I don't want to introduce an extra serializer for this two fields, and looking forward if this could be achieved with the same nested serializer.

- Every Device instance contains `config`.

#### In short:-

I am trying to use the same `DeviceConfigSerializer`, for both `DeviceListSerilaizer`, and `DeviceDetailSerializer`. But for the `DeviceListSerializer` I want the `status`, & `backend` field from the `DeviceConfigSerializer`to be both read & write, which is presenty set to write only for the `DeviceListSerializer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, so I had to introduce two new serializers for my need.

Answer (score 0):

`PrimaryKeyRelatedField` may be used to represent the target of the relationship using its primary key
For example, the following serializer:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'tracks']
```

Would serialize to a representation like this:

```
{
    'album_name': 'Undun',
    'artist': 'The Roots',
    'tracks': [
        89,
        90,
        91,
        ...
    ]
}
```

You can use this type of approach in your serializes. Reference https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield